# How do I create a ViewModel based on the DataContext object of a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been working with MVVM for a while, and this problem (if it is a problem) has me stumped all the time.

I have an ItemsControl bound to a collection in my MainViewModel

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <view:NameView />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The DataContext property of each  is of type string (bound directly to the Model), but what if I wanted the DataContext's to be bound to a ViewModel which is based on the property. How would I go about instantiating the ViewModel and feeding it the Model (string).

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the following?

```
public ObservableCollection<NameViewModel> Names { get; set; }
```

This seems a bit odd, but AFAIK there isn't a specific prohibition against one VM knowing about others.

In a case where you use DI for VM resolution, obviously your design would have to be adjusted.  For instance, you might create a `NamesView` which is a UserControl with a public `DependencyProperty` of type `IEnumerable<string>`.  Then, the `NamesView`'s ViewModel is bound to this DP...

Comment: When you say "there isn't a specific prohibition against one VM knowing about others" it rings some alarms in me that suggest otherwise. Is this a normal pattern for what is essentially "child ViewModels"? What I mean is, I thought ViewModels were not supposed to know about each other. Also, its not necessary for the MainViewModel to know about others, as the ChildViewModel is just supporting the new Model from the DataTemplate

Comment: @Mortick: It depends on how pure you wish to be.  I've never read anything about breaking dependencies between VMs, but I have seen people trying to do this using a message bus.  Frankly, there comes a point when striving for purity that you end up sending yourself to the gulag.  If it is convenient, easy to maintain and keeps your codebase small by allowing VM A to know about VM B, then let it be.

Comment: I'd go farther than Will:  that's not striving for purity, that's cargo-cult programming.  VMs need to be testable independent of the view.  That's the primary driver for the pattern.  Dependencies between VMs are like any other dependencies between classes:  they make testing a little more challenging, but are often perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about data template matching.

If you want binding to select the data template it uses to present an object at runtime, the simplest way is by putting the templates in the resource dictionary and setting their `DataType` property, e.g.:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
  <ItemsControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Thing1}">
        ...
     </DataTemplate>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Thing2}">
        ...
     </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now if your view model, instead of a `Names` property, has a `Things` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Things { get; set; }
```

you can populate the collection with `Thing1` and `Thing2` objects and the `ItemsControl` will present each with the appropriate template.

If you want to choose a different template based on the *value* of a property, there are a couple of ways of accomplishing this as well.  One is to write a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx), which gives you very fine-grained control over what template gets selected, but requires you to actually code (and test, and document) something.

Another is to use styles to display and hide content based on a trigger.  This doesn't actually select different templates per se, but it accomplishes more or less the same thing.  Put this in your item template, and it will display one set of content when `Name` is "Thing1" and another when `Name` is "Thing2".

A *very* nice thing about this approach is that unlike template selection, this is dynamic:  if the value of the `Name` property changes at runtime (and your view model implements property-change notification), so will what appears in the view.

```
<StackPanel>
   <ContentControl>
      <ContentControl.Style>
         <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Thing1">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ContentControl.Style>
      <!-- content to display when Name = Thing1 goes here -->
   </ContentControl>
   <ContentControl>
      <ContentControl.Style>
         <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Thing2">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ContentControl.Style>
      <!-- content to display when Name = Thing2 goes here -->
   </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

*Finally*, if what you're trying to do is actually create different view models in your collection based on the values of the string in the `Names` collection, you do that in the view model.  You could do this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> ViewModels
{
   get
   {
      foreach (string name in Names)
      {
         switch (name)
         {
            case "Thing1":  yield return new Thing1ViewModel(name);
            case "Thing2":  yield return new Thing2ViewModel(name);
            default:  throw new InvalidOperationException();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If the values in `Names` change at runtime, you have a substantially more complex problem:  you'll need to implement `ViewModels` as an `ObservableCollection<object>` property, and you may need to go so far as to handle collection-change events on the `Names` collection and update the `ViewModels` collection whenever an item in `Names` is added, removed, or changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it opened my eyes to a few other problems I had. Sadly though, your answer doesn't tackle the problem I described above.

Comment: In my defense, it wasn't the least ambiguous description I've ever read.  The above's a good answer for several of the questions you appeared to be asking.